# Найти строки в DataFrame, значения которых больше некоторого some_value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть некоторый DataFrame. Мне нужно найти строки, в которых все значения больше некоторого some_value. 
Пусть 
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 5], [4, 7, 8]])[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И пусть some_value = 3.
Получается, мне нужно получить строки, в которых все значения больше 3.
Это строкa '2'. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all(1) выберет те строки, в которых все значения True, то есть, в данном случае, больше 3

```
df[df.gt(some_value).all(1)]
   0  1  2
2  4  7  8
```